# Using CSS to make a ...window? Slide-over? Moving-text-thing?

Tags: css

I really have no idea what this is called and it's bugging the crap out of me.

I'm trying to use CSS to make a square tile that, when you hover over it, a black box with text slides in from the bottom over that tile. Like if you had a youtube video square, and if you hover over it, a black box slides in with the title or more information.

Can someone point me in the right direction, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean a tooltip?

Try this: http://csstooltip.com/

Answer (score 0):

unfortunetly u need to use javascript for that. There are some chance to do this with css but it will work realy bad in planty browsers (if you need for example animation after hovering u need to use css3 which is not used in planty of older browsers).

to do it with css read about pseudoclass :hover and transition in css

you need to know a lot about positioning elements in css.